# Dagger 2 with Java 8 error compilation

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

Dagger 2 don't work with java 8 and Jack enabled.Try to solve this problem with different versions of dagger 2.x Didn't help.  Works fine before but when I try to add Java 8 this error occurred:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.whitespace()Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
```

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.my.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true

    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'    
}
```

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Charmatcher.whitespace()` was introduced in Guava 19.  Looks like you have some code that compiles against Guava 19, but end up with something earlier than that on the classpath.

Comment: will you explain a little please?